# Avoiding a for loop (with temp variables) in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I need to compare 2 names to see if one of them is a nickname of the other. I have two columns of names in a data frame.

```
Names <- data.frame(In_Name = c("Gary",'John','James','William','Bill','Paul','Tom','Annie','Bella','Sue'),
                Match_Name = c('Garry','Jon','Jimmy','Paul','William','Pablo','Thomas','Anne','Belle','Susan'),stringsAsFactors = F)

Names[] <- lapply(Names, toupper)
Names$Match <- 0
```

I also have a nickname table which contains like pairs of nicknames. In the full set the names may appear in multiple rows of like pairs (As in the case of the 'Bella' rows below)

```
    NickName_Table <- data.frame(Names = c('Garrett,Garret,Gary,Garry'
                                           ,'Ian,John,Johnie,Johnnie,Johnny,Jon'
                                           ,'Jae,James,Jamey,Jay,Jaymes,Jem,Jemmy,Jim,Jimi,Jimmie,Jimmy'
                                           ,'Bill,Billie,Billy,Wil,Will,William,Willie,Willy'
                                           ,'Paul,Pauly,Paulie'
                                           ,'Maas,Thom,Thomas,Tom,Tomas,Tommie,Tommy'
                                           ,'Ann,Anna,Anne,Annette,Annie,Nan,Nancy,Nanette,Nannie,Nanny'
                                           ,'Bella,Belle,Ibbie,Issy,Izzy,Sabella'
                                           ,'Isabella,Isabelle,Bella,Belle'
                                           ,'Sue,Sukie,Susan,Susann,Susanna,Suzie'))
    NickName_Table[] <- lapply(NickName_Table, toupper)
```

I would like to avoid using a for loop however am unable to work out how to do it with a function call, as i need to store the found row in a temp variable, in order to search the second name for its presence in the same row/s. I need to do this for over a million pairs of names and the for loop is too slow. My current loop is:

```
library(sqldf)
i=1
for (i in 1:nrow(Names))
{

  first_name <- Names[i,1]
  match_name <- Names[i,2]

  if(!is.na(first_name) & !is.na(match_name) & first_name != match_name)
  {  
    if (nrow(subset(NickName_Table,grepl(first_name,NickName_Table$Names)))>= 1)
    {
      possibleMatch <- subset(NickName_Table,grepl(first_name,NickName_Table$Names))
      temp1 <- unique(as.data.frame(strsplit(gsub(" ", ",",Reduce(paste,unlist(possibleMatch))),","), stringsAsFactors = F))
      colnames(temp1) <- "Names"
      temp2 <- data.frame(match_name, stringsAsFactors = F)
      colnames(temp2) <- "Names_1"

      if(nrow(sqldf("Select a.* from temp1 a left join temp2 b on a.Names=b.Names_1 where b.Names_1 is not NULL"))>= 1)
      {
        Names[i,3] <- 1 
      }
      else
        Names[i,3] <- 0 
    }
    else
      Names[i,3] <- 0 
  }
  else
    Names[i,3] <- 0
}
```

EDIT:
I attempted to create a function however the issue is that the length of the nickname table, and the strings to be compared is unequal, so vectorised comparison seem to not work.

```
    functiona <- function (inNames,MatchNames,NickName_Table1){
  if(!is.na(inNames) & !is.na(MatchNames) & inNames != MatchNames)
  { 
    if (length(subset(NickName_Table1,grepl(inNames,NickName_Table1)))>= 1)
    {
      possibleMatch <- subset(NickName_Table1,grepl(inNames,NickName_Table1))
      temp1 <- unique(as.data.frame(strsplit(gsub(" ", ",",Reduce(paste,unlist(possibleMatch))),","), stringsAsFactors = F))
      colnames(temp1) <- "Names"
      temp2 <- data.frame(MatchNames, stringsAsFactors = F)
      colnames(temp2) <- "Names_1"

      if(nrow(sqldf("Select a.* from temp1 a left join temp2 b on a.Names=b.Names_1 where b.Names_1 is not NULL"))>= 1)
      {
        return <- 1 
      }
      else
        return <- 0 
    }
    else
      return <- 0 
  }
  else
    return <- 0
}

c <- mapply(functiona,Names$In_Name,Names$Match_Name,NickName_Table$Names)
```

Comment: Be more specific about your question. Explain, not only the problem, but what you have tried and what you are stuck with. Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can all be put into a single SQL statement.  We prepend and append a comma to `Names`, `In_Name` and `Match_Name` to be sure that we do not get partial matches and then left join (to ensure all rows of `Names` are kept) with `NickName_Table` using a condition that is true when there is a match of both `In_Name` and `Match_Name` to the same row of `Names`.  The SQLite function `instr` checks whether its first argument contains its second argument as a substring.

```
sqldf("select distinct In_Name, Match_Name, Names is not null as 'Match' 
       from Names 
       left join (select ',' || Names || ',' as Names from NickName_Table) 
       on instr(Names, ',' || In_Name || ',') and instr(Names, ',' || Match_Name || ',')")
```

giving:

```
   In_Name Match_Name Match
1     GARY      GARRY     1
2     JOHN        JON     1
3    JAMES      JIMMY     1
4  WILLIAM       PAUL     0
5     BILL    WILLIAM     1
6     PAUL      PABLO     0
7      TOM     THOMAS     1
8    ANNIE       ANNE     1
9    BELLA      BELLE     1
10     SUE      SUSAN     1
```

Answer (score 0):

No loops!

`sapply` is exponentially faster than loops. `merge` is faster too, specially with `data.table`.

```
require(data.table)
Names <- data.frame(In_Name = c("Gary",'John','James','William','Bill','Paul','Tom','Annie','Bella','Sue'),
                    Match_Name = c('Garry','Jon','Jimmy','Paul','William','Pablo','Thomas','Anne','Belle','Susan'),stringsAsFactors = F)

Names[] <- lapply(Names, toupper)
Names$Match <- 0

NickName_Table <- data.table(Names = c('Garrett,Garret,Gary,Garry'
                                       ,'Ian,John,Johnie,Johnnie,Johnny,Jon'
                                       ,'Jae,James,Jamey,Jay,Jaymes,Jem,Jemmy,Jim,Jimi,Jimmie,Jimmy'
                                       ,'Bill,Billie,Billy,Wil,Will,William,Willie,Willy'
                                       ,'Paul,Pauly,Paulie'
                                       ,'Maas,Thom,Thomas,Tom,Tomas,Tommie,Tommy'
                                       ,'Ann,Anna,Anne,Annette,Annie,Nan,Nancy,Nanette,Nannie,Nanny'
                                       ,'Bella,Belle,Ibbie,Issy,Izzy,Sabella'
                                       ,'Isabella,Isabelle,Bella,Belle'
                                       ,'Sue,Sukie,Susan,Susann,Susanna,Suzie'))
NickName_Table[] <- lapply(NickName_Table, toupper)

n              <- which(like(NickName_Table$Names,"BELLA"))
tmp            <- as.data.frame(paste(NickName_Table$Names[n[1]], NickName_Table$Names[n[2]])) # either tweak if you have > 2 in other cases or just count columnwise TRUE values in final sapply step below
colnames(tmp)  <- NULL
NickName_Table <- NickName_Table[!which(like(NickName_Table$Names,"BELLA")),]
NickName_Table <- rbind(NickName_Table,tmp)
NickName_Table$no <- 1:nrow(NickName_Table)

Names$nick_row <- sapply(Names$In_Name,FUN = function(x) which(grepl(x, NickName_Table$Names)))
Names          <- merge(x = Names, NickName_Table, by.x = "nick_row", by.y = "no")

Names$Match <- diag(sapply(Names$Match_Name, FUN =  function(x) grepl(x, Names$Names)))
Names$Names    <- NULL
Names$nick_row <- NULL
Names

Names
   In_Name Match_Name Match
1     GARY      GARRY  TRUE
2     JOHN        JON  TRUE
3    JAMES      JIMMY  TRUE
4  WILLIAM       PAUL FALSE
5     BILL    WILLIAM  TRUE
6     PAUL      PABLO FALSE
7      TOM     THOMAS  TRUE
8    ANNIE       ANNE  TRUE
9      SUE      SUSAN  TRUE
10   BELLA      BELLE  TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks. This one however doesn't check within the same string, it just checks for presence of both names within the data frame. I need to evaluate whether the second name can be found within any of the strings the first name was found in.

Comment: Hadley's presentation at Wombat2016; https://youtu.be/hRNUgwAFZtQ?t=47m33s "*a lot of people tell you not to use for loops because they are slow. That is complete and utter garbage.*" Exponentially faster might be an exaggeration.

Comment: Can you prove that "sapply is exponentially faster than loops."?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that a) you only want to know if the pair of `In_Name` and `Match_Name` exist in the same row of `Nickname_Table`, and b) you don't need to know *which* row they're on, then I think this does the trick:

```
## separate the nicknames into individual strings
splitlist <- sapply(NickName_Table, strsplit, ",")

## create a truth table where In_Name and Match_Name both exist on a row of Nickname_Table
truthMatrix <- sapply(1:nrow(Names), function(x) {
  sapply(1:length(splitlist), function(y) {
    match(Names$In_Name[x], splitlist[[y]])>0 & match(Names$Match_Name[x], splitlist[[y]])>0
  })
})

## assign the value as a match if there is at least one anywhere
Names$Match <- ifelse(is.na(apply(truthMatrix, 2, any)), 0, 1)

Names    
#>    In_Name Match_Name Match
#> 1     GARY      GARRY     1
#> 2     JOHN        JON     1
#> 3    JAMES      JIMMY     1
#> 4  WILLIAM       PAUL     0
#> 5     BILL    WILLIAM     1
#> 6     PAUL      PABLO     0
#> 7      TOM     THOMAS     1
#> 8    ANNIE       ANNE     1
#> 9    BELLA      BELLE     1
#> 10     SUE      SUSAN     1
```

This still needs to loop through `nrow(Names)*nrow(Nickname_Table)` values, but there's potentially some vectorisation to take advantage of.

For clarity, here's the value of truthMatrix:

```
truthMatrix
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#> [1,] TRUE   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
#> [2,]   NA TRUE   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
#> [3,]   NA   NA TRUE   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
#> [4,]   NA   NA   NA   NA TRUE   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
#> [5,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
#> [6,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA TRUE   NA   NA    NA
#> [7,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA TRUE   NA    NA
#> [8,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA TRUE    NA
#> [9,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA TRUE    NA
#> [10,]  NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA  TRUE
```

where you can see that 'Bella'/'Belle' matched on two occasions.

Comment: You'd probably want to return `FALSE` or `0` instead of `NA`

Comment: Updated to return 0 or 1.